# Android debug app is not opening using branch.io

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I am working on deeplinking part in android, I have found branch.io provides deeplinking support. I followed everything as per documentation but still it is opening custom link instead of app.

code:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="branch.next.com.newbranchapp">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

        <application
            android:name="io.branch.referral.BranchApp""
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                      android:launchMode="singleTask"
                >

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <!-- Branch URI scheme -->
                <intent-filter>
                    <data android:scheme="branch" android:host="open" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>
            <!-- Branch init -->
            <!-- Branch init -->
            <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_live_abFuXvh4EU7Yocf2FB4jJpccAEcz3sZT" />
            <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test" android:value="key_test_cbvEXCcXuJ27ojf1yu9sTkaitsoF0v9X" />

            <!-- Branch testing (TestMode "true" to simulate fresh installs on dev environment) -->
            <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="true" />



            <!-- Branch install referrer tracking -->
            <receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

        </application>

</manifest>
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();

        branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchUniversalReferralInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitFinished(BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject, LinkProperties linkProperties, BranchError error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    Log.i("MyApp","not working");
                } else {
                    Log.i("MyApp", error.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        this.setIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

// application

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: link also i am giving https://byya.test-app.link/PeWmihFSaF

Answer (score 1):

Amruta from [Branch.io](http://branch.io) here:

Two things:

1. The name of your Application class is "CustomApplication" but in your Manifest I see the name for your Application class set to "android:name="io.branch.referral.BranchApp"". I am not sure but I believe this should give you errors in your App. This should be set to ".CustomApplication"
2. I just took a quick look at your Branch dashboard. Since you are testing with a link from the test version of your app (Links from the test version have the link domain of the type ".test-app.link") you should populate the Android URL for the test version in your Link Settings. You can switch between the 'Live' and 'Test' using the flipper on the top-left corner of the dashboard.

[image: Live/Test Flipper]

Comment: first thing i changed .customapplication and second link i generated through branch.io is byya.test-app.link/PeWmihFSaF still not working please help me

Comment: why my link is not detecting my installed app in device

Comment: @skyshine it would be really great if you could reply the response I sent you via email.